# input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use custom ReactJS radio buttons but when I'm unable to get them to render as to which some errors are showing on my console, inside my component I've got the following:

```
D.div({ className: 'stra-on-loss' },
    D.span({ className: 'bet-title' }, 'On loss:'),
    ReactRadio({name: 'onLoss', onChange: this.updateOnLoss, defaultValue: this.state.onLossSelectedOpt  },
        D.input({
            type: 'radio',
            className: 'stra-on-loss-return-to-base-radio',
            value: 'return_to_base',
            disabled: this.state.active
        },  D.span(null, 'Return to base bet')),
        D.input({
            type: 'radio',
            className: 'stra-on-loss-increase-bet-by',
            value: 'increase_bet_by',
            disabled: this.state.active
        },  D.span(null, 'Increase bet by: '), 
        D.input({
            type: 'text',
            ref: 'onLossQty',
            onChange: this.updateOnLossQty,
            value: this.state.onLossIncreaseQty,
            disabled: this.state.active || this.state.onLossSelectedOpt !== 'increase_bet_by' }
        ), D.span(null, 'x'))
    )
)
```

But then I've also got a class that's imported `ReactRadio` which handles the buttons:

```
return CreateReactClass({

    displayName: 'reactRadio',

    propTypes: {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.string,
        defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
        onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.update();
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function() {

    },

    update: function() {
        if(this.props.defaultValue && !this.props.value)
            this.setSelectedRadio(this.props.defaultValue);
    },

    change: function() {
        if(!this.props.value)
            this.props.onChange(this.getSelectedRadio());
    },

    getSelectedRadio: function() {
        const radios = this.getRadios();
        for(let i=0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
            if(radios[i].checked)
                return radios[i].value;

        return null;
    },

    setSelectedRadio: function(value) {
        const radios = this.getRadios();
        for(let i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
            if(radios[i].value === value)
                radios[i].checked = true;
    },

    getRadios: function() {
        return this.getDOMNode().querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    },

    render: function() {
        const self = this;
        return D.div({ onChange: this.change },
            React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
                let newProps = {name: self.props.name};
                if(child.props.children) {
                    React.Children.map(child.props.children, function (child) {
                        if (child.props.onChange) {
                            var childrenChange = child.props.onChange;
                        }
                        _.extend(child.props, {
                            onChange: function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                if (childrenChange)
                                    childrenChange();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                if(self.props.value) {
                    if (child.props.value !== self.props.value)
                        newProps.disabled = true;
                    else {
                        newProps.checked = true;
                        newProps.readOnly = true;
                    }
                }
                _.extend(child.props, newProps);
                return child;
            })
        )
    }
});
```

When I visit my browser I'm getting the following in my console & the component isn't being loaded: **Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of AutoBetWidget.**